# Ubuntu 15.10: how to disable self-tests on SMART hdd

Tags: hard-drive, 15.10

I used gnome-disks to disable self-tests and self-tests were disabled. I rebooted and self-tests were (re)enabled again and again and again. So it didn't work. I installed smartctl and I disabled SMART for my hdd and it didn't work. I used systemd to create a timer to disable every four minutes SMART for my hdd (though when I ran smartctl -a /dev/sda it does appear to be disabled) and (surprise, surprise!) it didn't work. I don't, I Do Not, I DO NOT want any more self-tests. What should I do?